# Rewrite using .htaccess one with index.php other with query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

using .htaccess, how can i rewrite url, so when visitor type:

`mydomain.com/` `mydomain.com/index.php`

`mydomain.com/LiveappGame` `mydomain.com/game.php?gid=LiveappGame`

This only works from one 2nd url 1st one is not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+|)/?$ game.php?gid=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `DirectoryIndex` directive for first URLs and for 2nd ones you need correction in regex. You can use this code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ game.php?gid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```